# Coldfusion 11 java.nio.file.FileSystemException Error

Tags: java, jar, coldfusion

I am creating a pdf by using the following jar files:

- avalon-framework-4.2.0.jar
- batik-all-1.7.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- fop-0.9.5.jar
- xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar
- xmlgraphics-commons-1.3.1.jar

These are loaded via:

```
THIS.javaSettings = { LoadPaths = [ "jar/lib/" ]
        , loadColdFusionClassPath=false
        , reloadOnChange=true
        , watchInterval=300
   }
```

.. inside my Application cfc. When I run the code from Chrome or IE it creates the pdf just fine, but when the page is refreshed I get the below error. What's funny is it works completely fine when run from Firefox. Can anyone help with this error or explain why it is happening?

> Error occurred while copying the file from source
>   C:/Inetpub/wwwroot/TestSite/MenuMaker/jar/lib/batik-all-1.7.jar to
>   C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/tmpCache/appClasses/1512258339
>
> **Resources:** Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are
>   using the correct syntax. Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution
>   to your problem.
>  
>   **Browser:**      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135
>   Safari/537.36
>  
>   ...
>
> ```
> java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\tmpCache\appClasses\1512258339\batik-all-1.7.jar:
> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process.
>
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.copy(WindowsFileCopy.java:165)
>   at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.copy(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:278)
>   at java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1274)
>   at coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.nioCopy(FileUtils.java:1368)
>   at coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1361)
>   at coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1326)
>   at coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.copy(FileUtils.java:492)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.AppClassLoaderHelper.handleDynamicLoading(AppClassLoaderHelper.java:380)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.AppClassLoaderHelper.init(AppClassLoaderHelper.java:189)
>   at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:325)
>   at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
>   at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
>   at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:142)
>   at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
>   at coldfusion.filter.BrowserDebugFilter.invoke(BrowserDebugFilter.java:78)
>   at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
>   at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
>   at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
>   at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
>   at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>   at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
>   at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
>   at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
>   at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
>   at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
>   at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> ```

Comment: I think I may have solved my own problem. First I was mistaken about the different behavior based on the browser. What I believe was causing the issue even though I am not sure why was having the reloadOnChange=true in the Coldfusion LoadPaths. I changed it to false and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Sounds like a plausible explanation. `reloadOnChange=true` involves CF manipulating dynamic jar and class files. That could certainly result in the error message above. (Though unless you updated the jar files, CF should not be attempting to reload anything.)  Anyway, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Coldfusion is thinking that some or all of the jar files are being updated, why I am not sure. Changing the LoadPaths:reloadOnchange=true attribute to false fixed the issue.